# How to make ssrs report parameters show up always

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

When I deploy my report to SSRS server and I have actions to go to various reports in the reports the parameters don't show up when I "GOTO ACTION" to another report.  How do I get the parameters to always show up?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set `ShowParameterPrompt` property to `true`. Take a look here for more information: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.showparameterprompts.aspx)

Comment: Can you give more detail?